# Webjob is not publishing with correct configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

During publish I selected Testing as configuration but it automatically change to "Release" after I click publish. And after publish completed it convert back to "Testing".

[click here to see full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhit.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct - it does revert to Release by default. I've raised an issue with this to get the acceptance of debug allowed in the experience and will push to try to get it back in there. FWIW, you can still debug a Web App with a WebJob in it if you enable remote debugging on the site.

Comment: What is the debugging experience if you "enable remote debugging on the site", but have a release binary?   Also, doesn't this problem also affect x86/x64 selection as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955272/publish-as-azure-webjob-doesnt-honor-solution-platform-configuration-vs